Keycloak: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No scheme supplied
I am trying to run KeyCloak server and FastAPI application locally. I am following this tutorial https://fastapi-keycloak.code-specialist.com/quick_start/
My actions:
1 Created docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.11
    container_name: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak_server:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.2
    volumes:
      - ./realm-export.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm.json
    container_name: keycloak_server
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: 
        - start-dev 
        - --import-realm

    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8280:8080

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Faced with error in the tutorial and fixed according to this https://howtodoinjava.com/devops/keycloak-script-upload-is-disabled/ (removed authorizationSettings)
I see the following log
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:02,620 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: localhost, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: false
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:03,742 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:04,447 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:04,566 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:04,615 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:04,892 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Triskaidekaphobia' 13.0.10.Final
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:05,275 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: node_591749, Site name: null
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:05,281 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:06,011 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (main) KC-SERVICES0003: Not importing realm Test from file /opt/keycloak/bin/../data/import/realm.json.  It already exists.
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:06,024 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (main) KC-SERVICES0003: Not importing realm Test from file /opt/keycloak/bin/../data/import/realm.json.  It already exists.
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:06,163 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Keycloak 20.0.2 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.13.3.Final) started in 4.937s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:06,163 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile dev activated. 
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:06,163 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, jdbc-h2, jdbc-mariadb, jdbc-mssql, jdbc-mysql, jdbc-oracle, jdbc-postgresql, keycloak, logging-gelf, narayana-jta, reactive-routes, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-metrics, vault, vertx]
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:06,209 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (main) KC-SERVICES0010: Failed to add user 'admin' to realm 'master': user with username exists
keycloak_server  | 2024-04-13 18:30:06,210 WARN  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.KeycloakMain] (main) Running the server in development mode. DO NOT use this configuration in production.

I am not sure that error Failed to add user 'admin' to realm 'master': user with username exists is critical (I think it happens because of the second run of the docker-compose file)
Then I am running FastAPI application python app.py (file and configs copied from tutorial)
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from fastapi_keycloak import FastAPIKeycloak, OIDCUser

app = FastAPI()
idp = FastAPIKeycloak(
    server_url="http://localhost:8280/auth",
    client_id="test-client",
    client_secret="GzgACcJzhzQ4j8kWhmhazt7WSdxDVUyE",
    admin_client_secret="BIcczGsZ6I8W5zf0rZg5qSexlloQLPKB",
    realm="Test",
    callback_uri="http://localhost:8081/callback"
)
idp.add_swagger_config(app)
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('app:app', host="127.0.0.1", port=8081)

An see this error:
idp = FastAPIKeycloak(
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/33_keykloak_fastapi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi_keycloak/api.py", line 165, in __init__
    self._get_admin_token()  # Requests an admin access token on startup
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/33_keykloak_fastapi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi_keycloak/api.py", line 349, in _get_admin_token
    response = requests.post(url=self.token_uri, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/33_keykloak_fastapi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/33_keykloak_fastapi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/33_keykloak_fastapi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 575, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/33_keykloak_fastapi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/33_keykloak_fastapi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 368, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/33_keykloak_fastapi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 439, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant https://None?

